# Using Angular Material 2 Tabs Component with Angular 4.0.0-rc.1

Tags: angular, angular-material

I recently updated my project from Angular 2.4.6 to to Angular 4.0.0-rc.1 after which Angular 2 Material 2 Tab component doesn't seem to work properly.

When I switch tabs the contents overlaps with each other.

Apparently because, the latest RC introduced  and deprecated  and template attribute.

Can anyone please guide how to overcome this issue, while the material add support for Angular 4?

Answer (score 11):

It because animation doesn't work with current configuration.

Accordignly to [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#animation-package)

> Animation Package
>
> We have pulled Animations into their own package. This means that if
>   you don’t use Animations, this extra code will not end up in your
>   production bundles. This also allows you to more easily find
>   documentation and to take better advantage of autocompletion. If you
>   do need animations, libraries like Material will automatically import
>   the module (once you install it via NPM), or you can add it yourself
>   to your main NgModule.

So what we need to do?

1) `npm i --save @angular/animations`

2) add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to imports array of `@NgModule`

```typescript
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatTabsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you use systemjs then don't forget about config:

```typescript
'@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations@next/bundles/animations.umd.js',
'@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MSfMM3zZTCqxv3cuPg00?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you so much yurzui. With angular cli when running ng build --prod --aot I am receiving below error, can you please guide?
ERROR in vendor.e60455e679cd619355b7.bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (AnimationEngine) [vendor.e60455e679cd619355b7.bundle.js:28085,6]

Comment: What angular-cli version are you using? Have your tried it with `v1.0.0-rc.0`? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-rc0-2017-02-25

Comment: Yes I am using @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0

Comment: Btw since angular cli@1.0.0-beta.28  `--aot`defaults to true in `--prod` or am i wrong? Let me try

Comment: I am running `ng new tabs --ng4` to test it

Comment: So its an already open issue. BTW I generated my project using exact same command i.e. with `--ng4` switch.

Comment: Yes, the same issue

Comment: One observation btw the changelog says "If you do need animations, libraries like Material will automatically import the module" so doesn't it mean that when we import MaterialModule from @angular/material it also imports BrowserAnimationsModule?

Comment: I think it's related with https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14730 See my output https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14737#issuecomment-282575602

Comment: @angular/material has not released yet new version that is compatible with angular@v4.0.0-rc.1

Comment: I see, I was going through the issue on github and seen the same screenshot. Its probably the class keyword.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install materials, animation and the cdk

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

2) in your app.module.ts

```
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, 
    MatTabsModule 
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```